# Excel VBA Error 13 type mismatch in Me.ActiveControl

Tags: vba, excel

I'm creating a commmon validation subroutine for a form with multiple text boxes.
For each of the textbox I have an Exit event that triggers the following:

```
Private Sub formatoNumerico(Optional ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Dim tb As MSForms.TextBox
  Set tb = Me.ActiveControl

  ' Do something
```

This is generating an Error 13 Type Mismatch on the 3rd line of the code, why?

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Its being called when ActiveControl is not a TextBox, add `MsgBox TypeName(Me.ActiveControl)` as the first line and see what the active control is

Comment: I get MultiPage (because the textbox is in one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab host control is a container so it takes precedence over its constituents.

The simplest thing is to pass the textbox to `formatoNumerico` otherwise you will need to identify the textbox by asking the current tab for its `ActiveControl`:

```
Private Sub formatoNumerico(Optional ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
  Dim tb As MSForms.TextBox

  If Not (Me.ActiveControl Is Nothing) Then
    If TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is MultiPage Then
      Set tb = Me.ActiveControl.Pages(Me.ActiveControl.Value).ActiveControl
    Else
      Set tb = Me.ActiveControl
    End If

    Debug.Print tb.Name
  End If

End Sub
```

Also note that switching between controls on different tabs wont raise `_Exit`.

Answer (score 0):

When you exit, the `Textbox` is no longer the active control, hence, when you try to set a textbox type variable to the current control (which may or may not be the textbox), this error will result.

You will need to modify your code to explicitly refer to the `TextBox` control you are interested in modifying. You may, perhaps, refer to it using some global variable at the time of initializing your forms and then use that reference in your code.

Comment: I want to avoid multiplying the number of variables (in this case textboxes) because there are many in this form. Is it possible to pass the reference of the textbox triggered by the exit event to this common procedure?

Comment: I am not sure of your use scenario, but perhaps an `AfterUpdate` or a `BeforeUpdate` might suit your purposes better. Google for these two and you'll find MSDN references and examples for the same.